# Implementing user/role/task security in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, security

Back in 2008 I remember running into a 3rd party tool that did 99.9% of the work of implementing task/role security.  From what I recall it was simply an extension of what was built into .Net.  You ran a script to add all the needed tables to your SQL Server then used the UI to go in and define all the tasks and then grouped the tasks into roles.  The assigned users to a role.  The power was that different roles could have the same task and it was all configured by the UI tool that came with this system.  I also thought it was on CodePlex, but I don't recall the name.  All I recall it was Microsoft's name with like Sql or something added to the name of it.

At the time, 2008 (VS2008 days), I was told by co-workers that Microsoft was slowing consuming the whole system into .net.

Anyone have any idea what the name of the thing was I am thinking of?  Is it part of Microsoft .Net now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps thinking of [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/), which uses a similar authorization model to Microsoft AzMan?  Or perhaps you're thinking of AzMan itself, which has a UI and allows storage in SQL Server?